# What is this iOS Accessibility UI element, and how is it enabled/disabled?

Tags: ios, usability, uiaccessibility

I have members complaining that they are unable to tap certain buttons located in a custom navigation bar at the top of my iOS app. The common complaint is that when they do attempt to tap, they see UI that looks like this:

[image]

This is about a 200x200 pixel square that appears over the middle of the screen.

We have no code in our app that is capable of drawing that kind of UI. I can only assume this is being triggered by some kind of iOS UI or Usability setting. The only thing I can think of is that we also have a UITabBarController, and the user (in this case) happens to be on the "Browse" tab of my app. If possible, I would like to either a) programmatically disable this or b) inform the user how he can manually disable this UI via an iOS setting someplace.

Can anyone identify what might trigger the UI you see above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a new feature of iOS 11. Take a look at [Bar Item Images](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-9-vector-images/).

To disable this you should remove an image from Accessibility on Bar Item (see link). But I am not sure how (or even whether) you can define that a user has enabled large content text.

For more info take a look at [What's New in Accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/215/).

Comment: Aha - you are correct. To enable this functionality, be running iOS 11, turn on one of the larger accessibility text sizes, then tap-and-hold on a button and it will show a "Bar Item Image". If you tap quickly it will still work correctly, but if you are a "slow tapper", which one might be if you require accessibility settings, the UI Accessibility functionality will intercept your tap and display a bar item image instead of registering the tap and taking the navigation action.